# How to safely remove folder without removing contents of a junction?

Tags: cmd, ntfs, junction

I've been search for a shell (cmd) solution for this for a while and haven't found any. So I wanted to create a Junction but first I need remove the folder if it exists ([Junction from sysinterals](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896768.aspx) won't let me ovewrite this).

My first solution was to to run `rmdir /S/Q folder\to\be\overwritten`. But if I re-run the script and `folder\to\be\overwritten` is already a link pointing to e.g. `common\folder` than contents of `common\folder` will be whipped out. Not good ;-).

So how to safely remove folder but only that folder in Windows command line? Also note that I need this to work in Windows XP.

Answer (score 0):

The answer I found well... works.

```
rem ad-l means directories but not links (symlinks or hardlinks)
for /f %%d in ('dir /ad-l /b .\folder\to\be') do @if [%%d]==[overwritten] rmdir /S /Q .\folder\to\be\overwritten
rem adl means directories which are links (symlinks or hardlinks)
for /f %%d in ('dir /adl /b .\folder\to\be') do @if [%%d]==[overwritten] rmdir .\folder\to\be\overwritten
```

Note that in this example `folder\to\be` contains folder (or link) named `overwritten` which is to be removed.